# cannot log in to google cloud master node root

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform, root

I  am  very new to this stuff and do not have much experience with linux - any help would  be highly appreciated.

I am unable to login as root - I seem to be getting the following error when I sudo su root:
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

It seems the permissions on the sudo executable has somehow been changed to full permissions, ie. 777

How can I change the permissions on this as we do not know the root password?

Is there some sort of default root password or any other way to change these permissions?

Comment: Did you accidentally chown /usr/bin/sudo? You may need to discard your instance(s) and launch new ones.

Comment: Hi
It seems that is the case - when I check the permissions on that, it shows the full 777 permissions instead of the standard.

Comment: Is  there no way to recover this instance?